# Given a timestamp, how to get 1 month ago

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm trying to build a method where I pass a month and can then query for the previous month dynamically.

```
total_churn(month)
   last_month = month - 1
   companies = Company.where("created_at BETWEEN '#{last_month}' AND '#{month}')
   return companies.count
 end
```

How do I pass the method 'month' in a way where I can dynamically determine the last month using ruby on rails? Thanks

Comment: so you want to pass a string like "January" or an integer like 1?

Comment: I can pass whatever makes sense to dynamically determine 1 month ago, and then query postgres. Thanks

Comment: The method is not to rely on the current month. But month based on what is passed to the method.

Comment: how would this method account for years? if you have 2 years of data you would just be able to grab one of them.

Comment: This ended up working: 'DateTime.parse('2012-09-01 00:00:00.000000') - 1.month'

Comment: You need to escape your sql query with ?. Your current query is susceptible to SQL injection. Also ruby automatically returns the last line of a method. No need to say return.

Comment: @AnApprentice Great question. Would you be so kind to accept one of our answers if they were of help to you? Thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
My suggestion: accept a date rather than a month.
total_churn(date)
   month_previous = date - 1.month
   companies = Company.where("created_at BETWEEN ? AND ?, '#{month_previous}', '#{date}')
   return companies.count
end

Current month:
Time.now.month
Date.today.month

Time or day one month ago:
(Time.now - 1.month).month
(Date.today - 1.month).month

...also equivalent to:
Time.now.month - 1
Date.today.month - 1

Previous month for any given date:
@date - 1.month
```

I would personally build your method to accept a date rather than just a month number. As long as the created_at field is storing dates, you'll need to give the query two dates for it to run, even if those dates are the 1st.

Comment: It's not the current_month. This question is around passing a set month, whatever month desired.

Comment: @AnApprentice Then substitute the date you want for 'Date.today' or 'Time.now'. It will still work.

Answer (score 1):

Rails has some helpful time helpers to create upper and lower bounds for your query. (`beginning_of_month` and `end_of_month` in the [Time class](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Time.html))

This method is also properly escaped with question marks instead of string interpolation, which is open to SQL injection attacks.

```
def total_churn(month)
  companies = Company.where('created_at BETWEEN ? and ?',(Time.now - 1.month).beginning_of_month,(Time.now - 1.month).end_of_month)
  companies.count
end
```

I would also say that this will only work for the most recent year. If you want to be able to query for earlier data, you may want to either add a year param or simply pass in a date and let it use that in place of `Time.now`.

```
# with separate year and month params
def total_churn(month, year)
  date = DateTime.parse("#{year}/#{month}/01")
  companies = Company.where('created_at BETWEEN ? and ?',(date - 1.month).beginning_of_month,(date - 1.month).end_of_month)
  companies.count
end

# with a random date input
def total_churn(date_in_month)
  companies = Company.where('created_at BETWEEN ? and ?',(date_in_month - 1.month).beginning_of_month,(date_in_month - 1.month).end_of_month)
  companies.count
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You need at least 2 parameters to accomplish this, one for the month and one for the year.  This is needed to establish what month you want.

```
def total_churn(year, month)
  date = Date.new year, month
  one_month_ago = date - 1.month
  ...
```

However, if you already have a date object, then you can use sscirrus' answer.  If the date is in a string, you'd probably want to parse it first (like in your comment)

```
def total_churn(date_string)
  date = Date.parse(date_string)
  one_month_ago = date - 1.month
  ...

>> date_string = '2012-09-01 00:00:00.000000'
>> total_churn date_string
```